# SQL Locking - Timeout issue

Tags: locking

I have a SQL job which kind of process a queue of requests. It updates Table1. It is long process that takes like 15 minutes.

Meanwhile my application tries to read records from Table1 and displays them in a grid. The corresponding get proc has set tran isolation level read uncommited.
When the SQL job is running, my application always time outs while populating the grid. If the SQL job is not running it works fine.

My proc has appropriate isolation level, so I'm not getting why it still time out.
Thoughts?

Here is how my get proc looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyGetProc(...)
```

AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ...
        FROM 
            dbo.Table1
            LEFT JOIN dbo.OtherTable1
        WHERE ...
        GROUP BY
         ...
    ) X
    INNER JOIN dbo.OtherTable2
    LEFT JOIN dbo.OtherTable3
    LEFT JOIN dbo.OtherTable4
    LEFT JOIN dbo.OtherTable5
    LEFT JOIN dbo.OtherTable6
    LEFT JOIN dbo.OtherTable6
ORDER BY
    ...
```

END

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the code that is timing out?  You'll get much stronger answers this way.

Comment: I added get proc code snippet in original thread

Answer (score 1):

use

Select * from table1 with (nolock)

which reads commited data.

Comment: I tried using WITH (NOLOCK) & SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; both at once and separately. But still the same issue.